# unable to create efs secondary gid via terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-efs

any clues why my secondary gid is not accepted here? I'm using terraform 0.14.10 and getting this error:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on main.tf line 101, in resource "aws_efs_access_point" "efs_pt":
  101:     secondary_gids  = 1001

Inappropriate value for attribute "secondary_gids": set of number required.
```

My terraform code:

```
resource "aws_efs_access_point" "efs_pt" {
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id

  posix_user {
    gid             = 1000
    uid             = 1000
    secondary_gids  = 1001
  }

  root_directory {
    creation_info {
      owner_gid   = 1000
      owner_uid   = 1000
      permissions = 755
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lagot I guess the issue is you are passing only one value, whereas terraform is expecting a set of numbers.

According to the error message, the provider is expecting an argument value of type set(numbers), and you have provided a number(1001). You can fix this by providing a value consistent with the type expected by the provider according to the error message:

Try something like below

```
secondary_gids = [1001]
```